# Expanding And Collapsing Toolbar In Android

Tags: android, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I am implementing expanding and collapsing toolbar with the help of collapsing toolbar but I am stuck when my toolbar is collapsed I want to show different toolbar. I have seen so piece of code but cannot be able to find my solution.
I have also seen the solution of one of the amazing developer https://github.com/saulmm/CoordinatorLayoutExample but cannot be able to find out my solution properly

[image]

This is my piece of code which i have implemented

activity_collapsing_toolbar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="176dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">


            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@color/base_color_theme_new"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/rl_class_image"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
                    android:gravity="center">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/ll_class"
                        android:layout_width="60dp"
                        android:layout_height="60dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/rounded_white_circle"
                        android:gravity="center">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/iv_class_image"
                            android:layout_width="60dp"
                            android:layout_height="60dp"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:padding="8dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/class_4" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </RelativeLayout>


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_class_name"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/rl_class_image"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="MATHEMATICS"
                    android:textSize="17sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_videos_test"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/tv_class_name"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="20 VIDEOS | 5 TESTS"
                    android:textSize="10sp" />


            </RelativeLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_corners_for_list"
        android:fillViewport="true"

        app:behavior_overlapTop="10dp"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">


        <!--<include layout="@layout/activity_chapters" />-->
        <com.chalklit.widget.NonScrollListView
            android:id="@+id/lv_modules_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:divider="@null"
            android:scrollbars="none"></com.chalklit.widget.NonScrollListView>


    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

CollapsingToolbarActivity.java

```
private CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbarLayout = null;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);


    setContentView(R.layout.activity_collapsing_toolbar);

    final Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_main);

    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    collapsingToolbarLayout = (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.collapsing_toolbar);
    collapsingToolbarLayout.setTitle(" ");
    collapsingToolbarLayout.setContentScrimColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.base_color_theme_new));
    collapsingToolbarLayout.setStatusBarScrimColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.base_color_theme_new));
}
```

Comment: You have `.setTitle(" ");`. I assume you wanted `.setTitle("Mathematics")`? Otherwise, yes, your toolbar is blank - is that your problem? That example code you linked to also handles the round image...

Comment: #cricket_007 I cannot set Title ("Mathematics") when toolbar is expanded i want to move that mathematics textview when toolbar is collapsing

Comment: I'm confused what the problem is... This method handles the title. https://github.com/saulmm/CoordinatorBehaviorExample/blob/master/app/src/main/java/saulmm/myapplication/MainActivity.java#L67

Comment: u just need to set title as collapsingToolbarLayout.setTitle("YOUR TITLE"); and when you scroll the title will automatically move to toolbar

Comment: I wanted that image view should align right to back button and textview contains Mathematics should align right to imageview when toolbar is collapsing.I tried to execute the code of CoordinatorBehaviourExample but i cannot be able achieve my desired output.

Comment: If I will use setTitle("") then that title will not be in the center and not below that image

Comment: create a custom toolbar and set title and set visibility to ImageView when CollapsingToolbarLayout is collapsed.

Comment: #Himank shah Is it possible that i can change toolbar dynamically again and again when collapsing and expanding toolbar ?

Answer (score 17):

I have preperead two amaizing avatar collapsing demo samples with approach that doesn’t use a custom `CoordinatorLayoutBehavior`!

To view my samples native code: [*"Collapsing Avatar Toolbar Sample"*](https://github.com/SergeyBurlaka/CollapsingAvatarToolbarSample)

To read my  [*"Animation Collapsing Toolbar Android"*](https://medium.com/@anatoliy8827/how-to-animate-collapsing-avatar-toolbar-sample-f3f37ab6c35e) post on Medium.

---

**demo 1**[image]   **demo 2** [image]

---

Instead of use use a custom `CoordinatorLayoutBehavior` i use an `OnOffsetChangedListener` which comes from `AppBarLayout`.

```
private lateinit var appBarLayout: AppBarLayout

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_demo_1)
        ...
        appBarLayout = findViewById(R.id.app_bar_layout)

        /**/
        appBarLayout.addOnOffsetChangedListener(
                AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener { appBarLayout, i ->
                   ...
                    /**/
                    updateViews(Math.abs(i / appBarLayout.totalScrollRange.toFloat()))
                })
    }
```

### Demo 1

[image]

---

in `updateViews` method avatar changes the size and changes avatar’s X, Y position translation in first demo.

```
private fun updateViews(offset: Float) {

        ...

        /* Collapse avatar img*/
        ivUserAvatar.apply {
            when {
                offset > avatarAnimateStartPointY -> {
                    val avatarCollapseAnimateOffset = (offset - avatarAnimateStartPointY) * avatarCollapseAnimationChangeWeight
                    val avatarSize = EXPAND_AVATAR_SIZE - (EXPAND_AVATAR_SIZE - COLLAPSE_IMAGE_SIZE) * avatarCollapseAnimateOffset
                    this.layoutParams.also {
                        it.height = Math.round(avatarSize)
                        it.width = Math.round(avatarSize)
                    }
                    invisibleTextViewWorkAround.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, offset)

                    this.translationX = ((appBarLayout.width - horizontalToolbarAvatarMargin - avatarSize) / 2) * avatarCollapseAnimateOffset
                    this.translationY = ((toolbar.height  - verticalToolbarAvatarMargin - avatarSize ) / 2) * avatarCollapseAnimateOffset
                }
                else -> this.layoutParams.also {
                    if (it.height != EXPAND_AVATAR_SIZE.toInt()) {
                        it.height = EXPAND_AVATAR_SIZE.toInt()
                        it.width = EXPAND_AVATAR_SIZE.toInt()
                        this.layoutParams = it
                    }
                    translationX = 0f
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

to find `avatarAnimateStartPointY` and `avatarCollapseAnimationChangeWeight` (for convert general offset to avatar animate offset):

```
private var avatarAnimateStartPointY: Float = 0F
 private var avatarCollapseAnimationChangeWeight: Float = 0F
 private var isCalculated = false
 private var verticalToolbarAvatarMargin =0F
...
if (isCalculated.not()) {
    avatarAnimateStartPointY = 
                 Math.abs((appBarLayout.height - (EXPAND_AVATAR_SIZE + horizontalToolbarAvatarMargin)) / appBarLayout.totalScrollRange)

    avatarCollapseAnimationChangeWeight = 1 / (1 - avatarAnimateStartPointY)

    verticalToolbarAvatarMargin = (toolbar.height - COLLAPSE_IMAGE_SIZE) * 2
    isCalculated = true
 }
```

### Demo 2

[image]

---

avatar change his size and than animate move to right at one moment with top toolbar text became to show and moving to left.

You need to track states: `TO_EXPANDED_STATE` changing, `TO_COLLAPSED_STATE` changing,  `WAIT_FOR_SWITCH`.

```
 /*Collapsed/expended sizes for views*/
            val result: Pair<Int, Int> = when {
                percentOffset < ABROAD -> {
                    Pair(TO_EXPANDED_STATE, cashCollapseState?.second ?: WAIT_FOR_SWITCH)
                }
                else -> {
                    Pair(TO_COLLAPSED_STATE, cashCollapseState?.second ?: WAIT_FOR_SWITCH)
                }
            }
```

Create animation for avatar on state switch change:

```
   result.apply {
        var translationY = 0f
        var headContainerHeight = 0f
        val translationX: Float
        var currentImageSize = 0
        when {
            cashCollapseState != null && cashCollapseState != this -> {
                when (first) {
                    TO_EXPANDED_STATE -> {
                        translationY = toolbar.height.toFloat()
                        headContainerHeight = appBarLayout.totalScrollRange.toFloat()
                        currentImageSize = EXPAND_AVATAR_SIZE.toInt()
                        /**/
                        titleToolbarText.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                        titleToolbarTextSingle.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                        background.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this@Demo2Activity, R.color.color_transparent))
                        /**/
                        ivAvatar.translationX = 0f
                    }

                    TO_COLLAPSED_STATE -> {
                        background.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this@Demo2Activity, R.color.colorPrimary))
                        currentImageSize = COLLAPSE_IMAGE_SIZE.toInt()
                        translationY = appBarLayout.totalScrollRange.toFloat() - (toolbar.height - COLLAPSE_IMAGE_SIZE) / 2
                        headContainerHeight = toolbar.height.toFloat()
                        translationX = appBarLayout.width / 2f - COLLAPSE_IMAGE_SIZE / 2 - margin * 2
                        /**/
                        ValueAnimator.ofFloat(ivAvatar.translationX, translationX).apply {
                            addUpdateListener {
                                if (cashCollapseState!!.first == TO_COLLAPSED_STATE) {
                                    ivAvatar.translationX = it.animatedValue as Float
                                }
                            }
                            interpolator = AnticipateOvershootInterpolator()
                            startDelay = 69
                            duration = 350
                            start()
                        }
                       ...
                    }
                }

                ivAvatar.apply {
                    layoutParams.height = currentImageSize
                    layoutParams.width = currentImageSize
                }
                collapsingAvatarContainer.apply {
                    layoutParams.height = headContainerHeight.toInt()
                    this.translationY = translationY
                    requestLayout()
                }
                /**/
                cashCollapseState = Pair(first, SWITCHED)
            }
```

---

To view my samples native code: [*"Collapsing Avatar Toolbar Sample"*](https://github.com/SergeyBurlaka/CollapsingAvatarToolbarSample)

Comment: Very good answer, i really love answers with full github sample since with material design questions you can miss out a flag and try out all day long

Answer (score 10):

Here's another approach that doesn't use a custom `CoordinatorLayoutBehavior`.

It uses an `OnOffsetChangedListener` which comes from `AppBarLayout`.

Here's a snippet:

```
class OnOffsetChangedListener implements AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener {

        @Override
        public void onOffsetChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, int verticalOffset) {

            final int scrollRange = appBarLayout.getTotalScrollRange();
            float offsetFactor = (float) (-verticalOffset) / (float) scrollRange;
            ...
```

This shows you how to find the total scroll range and then find the ratio between the total scroll range and the current scroll position.  This is what you need to figure out how to scale and position your toolbar views.

For a custom layout (like I did), you can override `onAttachedToWindow` and add the listener there:

```
        // Add an OnOffsetChangedListener if possible
        final ViewParent parent = getParent();
        if (parent instanceof AppBarLayout) {
            if (mOnOffsetChangedListener == null) {
                mOnOffsetChangedListener = new OnOffsetChangedListener();
            }
            ((AppBarLayout) parent).addOnOffsetChangedListener(mOnOffsetChangedListener);
        }
```

I found this approach to be a little simpler than creating a custom behavior.

I created an example project on GitHub.  The app looks like this:

[image: App screenshots]

You can see the whole project at https://github.com/klarson2/Collapsing-Image

Comment: amazing... could make a tutorial video on youtube??

Answer (score 4):

you should add Line #33

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="192dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|snap|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:title="Collapsing"
            app:toolbarId="@+id/toolbar">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/nana"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp"
    app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/ax" />

</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/floating_action_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:baselineAlignBottom="false"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:src="@drawable/possetive"
    app:fabSize="normal"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/appbar_layout"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right"
    app:rippleColor="#E4D6D6" />


</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

To achieve this, we must have to create custom behavior using CoordinatorLayout.Behavior

Take into account two core elements: child and dependency:

The child is the view that enhances behavior, dependency who will serve as a trigger to interact with the child element. In your requirement the child is the ImageView and the dependency is the Toolbar, in that way, if the Toolbar moves, the ImageView will move too.

Please check some below links for custome behaviour toolbar demos

- http://www.devexchanges.info/2016/03/android-tip-custom-coordinatorlayout.html
- https://medium.com/google-developers/intercepting-everything-with-coordinatorlayout-behaviors-8c6adc140c26#.tfsd7ftkl