# How to open/close layout on click & also on scroll?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

[click here to check gif file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nbt1V.gif)

Hello I'm a beginner.
I want to create anim like calendar layout in gif file.

Queries :

1. Whenever I click on button (November show in gif file. I have button in toolbar in my project). layout (in my project image in place of calendar in gif) should open/close with slide anim.
2. Under image I have recycler view on scroll recycler view.the image should open/close.
3. When image get hide/visible I need to Know action is done.

Please help me to achieve this process.!

[Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/chwD0.gif)

I did it by using motion layout. Now I stuck in. I need to do another action when view is expand/collapse. How to do this in Java code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**motion_layout.xml**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/motion_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
app:layoutDescription="@xml/motion_scene"
app:showPaths="false"
tools:context=".views.fragments.ScheduledExpandCalFragment">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/calendar_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/appbar">

    <com.github.sundeepk.compactcalendarview.CompactCalendarView
        android:id="@+id/calendar_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="220dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        app:compactCalendarBackgroundColor="@color/colorAccent"
        app:compactCalendarCurrentDayBackgroundColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        app:compactCalendarCurrentDayIndicatorStyle="fill_large_indicator"
        app:compactCalendarCurrentSelectedDayBackgroundColor="@color/yellow"
        app:compactCalendarCurrentSelectedDayIndicatorStyle="fill_large_indicator"
        app:compactCalendarEventIndicatorStyle="small_indicator"
        app:compactCalendarTargetHeight="250dp"
        app:compactCalendarTextColor="#fff"
        app:compactCalendarTextSize="12sp" />

</LinearLayout>

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/scheduled_recyclerview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/image_margin_end"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/image_margin_end"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/image_margin_end"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/date_text_size"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/calendar_layout" />

<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:toolbarId="@+id/toolbar">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/cal_tabBar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/colorAccent">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/expand_cal"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/image_margin_end"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_menu" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/date_text"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/date_text_height"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/image_margin_end"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:paddingStart="@dimen/image_margin_end"
                    android:layout_toStartOf="@id/expand_cal"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                    android:paddingEnd="@dimen/image_margin_end"
                    android:text=""
                    android:textAlignment="gravity"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/date_text_size" />

            </RelativeLayout>

        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

**motion_scence.xml**

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <MotionScene xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:motion="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<Transition
    app:constraintSetStart="@id/start"
    app:constraintSetEnd="@id/end"
    app:duration="1000">

    <OnSwipe
        app:touchAnchorId="@+id/scheduled_recyclerview"
        app:touchAnchorSide="top"
        app:dragDirection="dragUp" />

    <OnClick app:target="@id/expand_cal"
        app:clickAction="toggle"/>

</Transition>

<ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/start">
    <Constraint android:id="@id/toolbar">
        <PropertySet app:alpha="1"/>
    </Constraint>
</ConstraintSet>
<ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/end">
    <Constraint android:id="@id/calendar_layout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">
    </Constraint>
    <Constraint android:id="@id/toolbar">
        <PropertySet app:alpha="1"/>
    </Constraint>
</ConstraintSet>
```

**Code in fragment/activity**

```
  motionLayout.setTransitionListener(new MotionLayout.TransitionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTransitionStarted(MotionLayout motionLayout, int i, int i1) {
            System.out.println("onTransitionStarted " + i + " i1 " + i1);
        }

        @Override
        public void onTransitionChange(MotionLayout motionLayout, int i, int 
 i1,floatv) {
            System.out.println("onTransitionChange " + i + " i1 " + i1 + " v " + v);

        }

        @Override
        public void onTransitionCompleted(MotionLayout motionLayout, int i) {
            System.out.println("onTransitionCompleted " + motionLayout + " int " + i 
 + " \n shouldShow " + shouldShow);
        }

        @Override
        public void onTransitionTrigger(MotionLayout motionLayout, int i, boolean b, 
 float v) {
            System.out.println("onTransitionTrigger " + i + " b " + b + " v " + v);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

See this answer-https://stackoverflow.com/a/53965315/10844305, I think you will have some idea. See documentation here-https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/appbar/AppBarLayout

Comment: I done expand/collapse through motion layout. But stuck in. I need to print log/ show toast when expand/collapse is performed in Java code.